# How to get a notification for an HTML Select element, when the option is already selected

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML Select element with 3 options. If the user selects the 3rd option, I would like to redirect them to a different page. My initial implementation was something like this:

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function handledropdown(e) {
 var profile = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
 //if the option selected is not 'Option3', do nothing
 if (profile == 'Option3') {
     window.location.href="some-page.php";
 }
}    </script>
```

HTML:

```
<select  id='test_dd' name='options' onChange='handledropdown(this)' >
  <option title='Option1' value='1' >Option1</option>
  <option title='Option2' value='2' >Option2</option>
  <option title='Option3' value='3' >Option3</option>
</select>
```

This sort of works, but if Option3 is already selected, the only way to trigger the onChange event is to unselect it and reselect it - simply clicking on it when it is already selected does not trigger the change event. I tried to solve this by adding onClick event handling, like so:

```
<select  id='test_dd' name='options' onChange='handledropdown(this)' onClick='handledropdown(this)' >
<option title='Option1' value='1' >Option1</option>
<option title='Option2' value='2' >Option2</option>
<option title='Option3' value='3' >Option3</option>
</select>
```

And this seems to work fine in Safari but in IE and Firefox, if Option3 is already selected, as soon as you click on the select element to open the options, you are redirected to the redirect page (and in Chrome it does not appear to work at all).

Any ideas how to get around this ?

Comment: One question, how is it possible to see selected third option, if when you click it it should redirect you to another page? I mean just when you select option3 you are moving to another site. Am I right ?

Comment: The simplest way it could happen is if the user hits "Back" in the browser after the redirect - now he's back to the original page, but Option3 is already selected in the select element

Answer (score 0):

just use

```
 $("#test_dd").mouseup(function() {
    var open = $(this).data("isopen");

    if(open) {
        if ($(this).val()=="3")
            alert("hi")
    }

    $(this).data("isopen", !open);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/prollygeek/UK6q8/2/

Comment: This doesn't work - in your jsfiddle example, comment out (or remove) the window redirect, leaving just the  alert - select Option3, it will work once. Now , when Option 3 is already selected, you can't get it to alert again by simply cicking Option3, you have to select  anoher option first, then reselect 3. this is equivalent to my initial implementation.

Comment: actually - it works - if you change the jsfiddle to 'onclick' - thanks!

Comment: oh sorry it is my mistake , i sent the right code , but forgot to update fiddle .

Comment: actually, on further checking, it doesn't work. the jquery code you sent, with 'change', is equivalent to my original implementation, and with 'click', it is equivalent to my s2nd attempt - that is, on IE and Firefox it fires up the alert as soon as you click on the select item, if Option 3 is already selected.

Comment: i dont get you , isnt that what you want ?? to fire upon selecting option 3 ?

Comment: oh ok ok got your problem , hold on